# Checking if a Process is running in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a shell script which I need to run quite often.

When the shell script starts I want to make sure to log the process Id to a log file.

How can I make sure that the process is still running using the logged process id.

Comment: ps, pgrep, kill, /proc...add some detail about how you call or identify the process and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @tristan It is not really a duplicate, since this here `bash` related whereas in the linked question are answers for `C`.

Comment: It's generally not safe to assume that a logged process ID still refers to the process that used it at the time of the logging. Use the tools your operating system already uses to monitor processes (Upstart, Daemontools, systems are just a few examples).

Comment: sorry i overlooked it. but you may try kill command in bash

Comment: @chepner : Can you provide any reading material or links on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the pid you can specifically ask ps for that process to determine if it is running.  An empty response means the pid is not running

ps PID

Comment: Does `ps` return empty response if no precess with this PID is running? As I know ps always returns headers eg. 'PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND' even PID is not found.

Comment: It returns headers but the status of the last command will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the PID, you can check `/proc/$PID/cmdline` to verify the process with that PID is what you expect. You need to do this to guard against PIDs being reused on rollover.

Comment: It says permission denied.

Comment: You can only see it if you read it as `root` user or as the UID that started the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `top` to monitor the process

```
top -p <pid>
```

Comment: top is not installed on the server, any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ps` to list running processes

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1555 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 1596 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to grep the output of `ps`:

```
 PID=$(cat pid-file)
 if ps -o pid -ax | grep -s $PID ; then
     # action if still running
 fi
```

As jman wrote, you can then check in `/proc/$PID/cmdline` if the process with the PID is the correct one or just another process. Remember that you can easily get race conditions and problems with [zombie processes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

Answer (score 0):

You can "ask" command `ps` if process with PID is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`cat /<path-to-the-lock-file>`
running=`ps -p $pid -o pid|head -n-1`
if [ "$running" != "" ]
then
    echo "Already running"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Its AIX OS, this format is returning error `ps: Not a recognized flag: -
ps: 0509-048 Flag -p was used with invalid list.
`

Comment: I changed an example. Must work on your OS, but I have no opportunity to test under AIX OS. Under Linux is still works.